# Anyway to enable sentry on cookiecutter-django after the fact?

Tags: python, django, cookiecutter-django

I created a django app using cookiecutter-django. While getting ready to deploy I realized I should have enabled sentry during project setup.  Am i out of luck here and need to redo everything? Or is there a way I can enable it?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but you can check this out: https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=log#settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add in the library yourself.  You can follow the instructions to install sentry here: https://raven.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/django.html

Comment: It is really easy to do.

Comment: I"m going to install it. It looks very easy. Only question is should I add raven and sentry to base requirements or production only?

Comment: You can add to both, but you would want a different raven project for each environment so you can seperate your logging between environments.